# How to use DataTable with RIA services?

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, wcf-ria-services

All of the examples I find on the web are about using EF with ria services.  My existing DAL has several methods that return datatable objects.  Is there any way to expose and then consume a datatable with RIA services?

Thanks!

Comment: Even if you could, it may be a better approach to convert the exposed DataTables into object collections and expose those.

Answer (score 1):

There's no DataTable in Silverlight, so it can't be exposed directly to SL. I'd follow the suggestion of @R0MANARMY to convert the tables into some sort of data contract, and use them in the domain service.

Comment: @subt13 DataTable is used for database access, given that you can't directly access the database but rather use other tools like ria services the datatable, moreover the whole System.Data namespace is excluded for the most part.

Answer (score 1):

What I have done previously is use the datatable to parse the xml, maybe even convert it to json. Then send it over the wire as a string and using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com) I converted it to the [telerik datatable](http://blogs.telerik.com/vladimirenchev/posts/09-04-23/lightweight_datatable_for_your_silverlight_applications.aspx) (Telerik not needed).

I've used this with about 800 000 rows, 10 columns and even though it does increase your memory alot i've not found an easier solution